# F3 framework localization slows down website

Tags: php, memcached, fat-free-framework

I've just implemented f3 localization on a platform I'm working on and it slowed down the website a lot.

On the setup.ini:

```
PREFIX=lang_
LANGUAGE=en
CACHE=TRUE
```

And then, I've a en.php file in the dict folder:

```
<?php
return array(
    'word1' => 'First word',
    'word2' => 'Second word',
    'word3' => 'Third word'
);
?>
```

To display words, I use: (and both work perfectly)

```
{{ @lang_word1}}
```

or

```
$f3->get('lang_word1');
```

The en.php file has almost 900 words / sentences and it looks like f3 loads it in every request and then the website gets super slow.

Any tips?

Cheers

Comment: how much is a lot? do you have any measurements?

Comment: @Joshua Doing the same request using locales: 2,6s and 0.9s without locales. I'm using the default cache system and it works perfectly. Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What about to use PHP [GETTEXT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) for translation?